# Python: Passing coordinates from text file to Turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have a test file that has coordinates on it my aim it to create a function that takes the text file and turns it into coordinates to plot in turtle to draw an image:

```
river, 5
500, 500
-500, 360
400, 500

shadow, 4
500, 300
5, 500
300, 400
```

so far I have the following

```
f =open("coordinates.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    line=line.split(",")
    data=[]
    if line:
        data.append([i.strip() for i in line])
```

After running I get the following:

```
    [['river', '5']]
    [['500', '500']]
    [['-500', 360]]
    [['400', '500']]
    [['']]
    [['shadow', '4']]
    [['500', '300']]
    [['5', '500']]
    [['300', '400']]
    [['']]
```

But when I pass it through turtle it breaks and does not work. My turtle function is as follows:

```
p=[]
letter=block[0]
for line in block[1:]:
          l.append(line)
k=p[0]
turtle.setpos(k[0],k[1])
```

Comment: What is the content of `block`?

Comment: Also can you be more specific on what breaks how and what does not work? Like which line raises which error etc

Comment: block comes from the file when rendered into a list

Comment: So `block` is equal to `data`? Or is it part of it?

Comment: Block is equal to data

Comment: What is `p`? Forgot to ask. It's very helpful to include your variable definitions, so we can see what data you're accessing etc

Comment: re-edited the code hope that helps

Comment: Is this the actual code? `k=p[0]` is accessing first element of `p` but `p` is empty

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a random collection of code rather than a program.  Below is my reconstruction of the intent of the program from the data and code.  The data gets read into a list as follows:

```
[('river', '5'), (500, 500), (-500, 360), (400, 500), ('shadow', '4'), (500, 300), (5, 500), (300, 400)]
```

And then drawn as lines with turtle.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(1000, 1000)

data = []

with open('coordinates.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.rstrip()

        if line:
            x, y = line.split(', ', maxsplit=1)

            try:
                data.append((int(x), int(y)))
            except ValueError:
                data.append((x, y))

print(data)

turtle.penup()

for pair in data:
    if isinstance(pair[0], int):
        turtle.setpos(pair)
        turtle.pendown()
    else:
        print('Drawing {} ({})'.format(*pair))
        turtle.penup()

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.done()
```

I can't say the example drawing is at all interesting:

[image]