# Passing Parameters as Coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with coordinates on it like the following example. My aim was to load the file and create it into coordinates to plug into turtle to draw something, but when I try the whole thing crushes.

```
super, 4
-500, -360
-500, 360
500, 360
500,-360

sand, 29
-400, -90
-450, 60
-400, 110
-300, 110
-250, 210
-200, 260
```

So far I have the following code. How would I make it into coordinate x and y intercepts.

```
file = open("coordinate.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    line_str = line.split(",")
```

Comment: What is your error output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Passing coordinates from text file to Turtle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125581/python-passing-coordinates-from-text-file-to-turtle)

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
line_str=[]
    for line in file:
        line_str.append(line.replace('\n','').split(","))
```

or

```
       line_str.append([line.rstrip("\n").split(",")])
    print line_str
```

Comment: I prefer `line.rstrip("\n")` ;-) Also, `[int(x) for x in line.rstrip("\n").split(",")]` may be useful.

Comment: Or just `line.strip()`.